# Excel.Chart.Export not working

Tags: c#, excel

I have excel file with multiple chart on a sheet. I get chart from excel and save it to picture.

My code:

```
workSheet = workBook.Sheets[1] as Excel._Worksheet;
Excel.ChartObjects chartObjects =(Excel.ChartObjects)workSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
int chartCount = chartObjects.Count;
for (int j = 1; j <= chartCount; j++)
{
     Excel.ChartObject chart = (Excel.ChartObject)chartObjects.Item(j);
     path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Img\" + chart.Chart.Name + ".bmp");
     chart.Chart.Export(path, "BMP", true);
}
```

but only blank picture is exported.

Please help me

Comment: Does it work with another file type (e.g., .PNG or .JPG)?

Comment: doesn't work with any file type

Comment: what's the `@` before `"Img\" + chart.Chart.Name + ".bmp")`?

Comment: @"Img\" instead of "Img\\". I created picture file with bitmap type but it is only empty file

Comment: hmmmm well c# is not my thing but in Excel i know you need, for a chart, to do `.Export(filePath as String, fileType as String, interactive as Boolean)`.  As long as you're concatenating the path correctly, this looks like it should work.

Comment: actually... my last comment doesn't make sense. If you are getting a blank file, the `path` is valid.  I have experienced this problem before -- I think the problem is that it takes 1-2 seconds to export the image to the path. You may be able to avoid the problem if you put a pause in your code to wait while this event is occurring.

Comment: I clarified my issue, ex: i have 5 chart on a sheet, but my code is created 2 picture and 3 blank picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exporting charts that are not at least partially visible on screen at the time of the call to .Export appears to result in the blank images.

Try adding a line of code to activate the chart to be exported before you export it (I ran into the same issue and this worked for me):

```
Excel.ChartObject chart = (Excel.ChartObject)chartObjects.Item(j);
path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Img\" + chart.Chart.Name + ".bmp");
chart.Activate(); //New line
chart.Chart.Export(path, "BMP", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and tried the .Activate trick, but that didn't help.  Based on the comment that the charts need to become at least partially visible, I tried out a simple delay loop just prior to the .Export line:

```
For i = 1 to N
  DoEvents
Next i
```

This fixed the issue.  With a bit of experimentation I found that N >= 3 worked, but if N = 1 or 2, or if I took the loop out, the code returned to outputting blank pictures.  I don't understand it, but thought I'd pass along my observations.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Xiaofu
Your information on chart Activation before exporting really helped me as I spent nearly a day scratching for a solution on my little Python project. Cheers.

For anyone looking for a Python script version to export Excel charts to GIF or PNG format, here's the code that worked for me:

```
# Python function to export an Excel chart to a GIF image format
# Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110752/export-charts-from-excel-as-images-using-python
def ChartExport(cwd, fileName):
    app = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    workbook_file_name = cwd + fileName
    workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(Filename=workbook_file_name)

    # WARNING: The following line will cause the script to discard any unsaved changes in your workbook
    app.DisplayAlerts = False

    i = 1   # There are multiple charts on the worksheet. So using a number suffix to add the output gif filename
    for sheet in workbook.Worksheets:
        for chartObject in sheet.ChartObjects():
            #print('i = ', i, ' -- ', sheet.Name + ':' + chartObject.Name)
            chartObject.Activate()  # This line was added after finding exporting problem with 2nd and 3rd charts. Thanks Xiaofu Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911536/excel-chart-export-not-working
            chartObject.Chart.Export(cwd + '\\chart' + str(i) + '.gif')  # Export chart to a gif file format
            i += 1

    workbook.Close(SaveChanges=False, Filename=workbook_file_name)
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this exact situation.  Unfortunately, using chart.Activate() didn't work for me.  However, the part about the chart having to be partially visible gave me a clue on what to do.  I just maximized the window, making all my charts visible, and the export started working again.

```
Excel.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;    
Excel.ChartObject chart = (Excel.ChartObject)chartObjects.Item(j);
path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Img\" + chart.Chart.Name + ".bmp");
chart.Activate(); //New line
chart.Chart.Export(path, "BMP", true);
```