# Using win32com via python to scrape excel file for chart objects and convert them to images

Tags: python, image, charts, win32com, import-from-excel

I am trying to scrape a `.xlsx` excel file for `chart objects` and export them as images. The only similar stackoverflow question I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110752/export-charts-from-excel-as-images-using-python) which attempts to do the same thing. The script, however, does not seem to work (even when I correct the syntax/methods). 
I am willing to get this running in either `Python 2.7.9` or `3.4.0.` as I have both versions running on my computer. 
**Here is the code I am working with:**

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application') 
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\Emilyn\Desktop\chartTest.xlsx') 
excel.Visible = True
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Select() 
wbSheetOne = wb.Sheets(1) 
wb.DisplayAlerts = False 
i = 0
    for chart in wbSheetOne.ChartObjects():
        print(chart.Name)
        chart.CopyPicture()
        excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After =excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3)).Name="temp_sheet" + str(i)
        temp_sheet = wb.ActiveSheet
        cht = wb.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects().Add(0,0,800,600)
        cht.Chart.Export("chart" + str(i) + ".png")
        i = i+1
excel.ActiveWorkbook.close
wb.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This opens my excel file, generates three `.png` images in my `documents` folder, and creates three new `worksheets` for the images, but the images are all blank.I am not sure what I can do to get the `chart objects` in my excel file to correctly copy to these newly created images. 
Any help I could get on this would be greatly appreciated as there seems to be no in depth documentation on `pywin/win32com` anywhere.

I've been searching the internet like mad and trying to get this to work for a day or two now... It's hard to get something to work when you don't know all of the methods available, or even what some of the methods do.

(Yes, I have read all the "read me" files that came with the library and read what they offered on their website as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already figured out what to do but I suppose I'll post it for future users.

```
for index in range(1, count + 1):
    currentChart = wbSheet.ChartObjects(index)
    currentChart.Copy
    currentChart.Chart.Export("chart" + str(index) + ".png")
```

I used a count to do a for loop, this way you dynamically read the amount of chart objects in an excel file.

Also, the reason I started the range at 1 is because VB in excel starts index of objects at 1, not zero.

Answer (score 0):

You copy an existing chart as a picture, but don't do anything with it.

You insert a worksheet, without adding any data, then you embed a chart in that worksheet, which must be blank since there's no data to display, then export the blank chart as a png file.