# Import excel2img gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, dependencies

After I did `pip install excel2img` , I am trying to run `import excel2img` but getting

```
'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'excel2img' .
```

The python version that I am running is 3.8.5

even tried `pip install pypiwin32` based on the error that I received while installing excel2img but of no help

Any help?

More info on error message

````
Collecting excel2img
  Using cached excel2img-1.4.0.tar.gz (24 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=3.3.1 in /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from excel2img) (8.0.1)
Collecting pypiwin32
  Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32->excel2img) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32->excel2img)```
````

Comment: look into "virtualenv"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python pip: force install ignoring dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759761/python-pip-force-install-ignoring-dependencies)

Comment: `excel2img` is a windows-only library and will not work on MacOS even if installed.

Comment: yes, Thanks @hoefling. I guess I should now look for an alternate solution. Same reason explained here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138235/save-chart-as-image-png-jpg-with-xlxswriter.