# Is there a way in python to write a image to a word file?

Tags: python, software-design

I have a sample image of a graph that is extracted from an excel file using a win32 package of python.

The implementation of the above is solved in this question = [extracting graphs as images from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110752/export-charts-from-excel-as-images-using-python)

Now, I want to read an image in python and write it to a doc file and save it. which ultimately gives me an output of somethig like this

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `add_picture()`-method of the following library:

[python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

This also gives you options for resizing and placement.

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue